# True or false: There is only one $n \times n$ matrix such that $(I_n-A)^{-1}=I_n-\frac{1}{n-1}A$

Tags: linear-algebra

There is only one $n \times n$ matrix that suits:

$(I_n-A)^{-1}=I_n-\frac{1}{n-1}A$

We know that:$(I_n-A)^{-1}\neq I_n-A^{-1} $ but I dont know what to do next:

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many matrices with that property. For example, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}nI_k&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $$I-A=\begin{pmatrix}-(n-1)I_k&O\\O&I\end{pmatrix}$$ $$(I-A)^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{n-1}I_k&O\\O&I\end{pmatrix}=I-\frac{1}{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}nI_k&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}$$ This is just one example. The size of $k$ can be varied, the diagonal terms can be permuted, and in general one can take any matrix of the form $P^{-1}AP$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $I_n=(I_n-A)(I_n-\tfrac{1}{n-1}A)$ iff $(A-\tfrac12nI_n)^2=\tfrac14n^2I_n$, any [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) $X$ of $I_n$ provides a solution $A=\tfrac12n(I_n+X)$.